# Migrating API from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 6 - doesn't open in web browser

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have migrated an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API to .NET 6. While running the app, it opens in a console instead as a browser. I have already set the properties to open as a windows application. I couldn't find what I am missing .

Comment: Do you get any error message ? What's your version of the visual studio ? Can you open a new project  an run it open in web browser ? Maybe you can refer the documentation from 2.1 to 2.2 till 5.0 to 6.0 and understand the changes you will need to make and apply them.[the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

> it opens in a console instead as a browser.

Please check and make sure `launchBrowser` is set to `true` in **launchSettings.json**, as below.

```
 "profiles": {
    "Your_Project_Name": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7141;http://localhost:5222",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```